# JQuery Append javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, append

I try to create modular application, so each page have contains own html and javascript code.
I supposed to load all code dynamically like:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src='function oncl() { alert("click");}';
$(".selector").append(s);

$( ".selector" ).
append('<input type="button" onclick="ocl();" />
<form action="../test/test_upload4.php"  
method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="getnamefile">
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile">
<input type="submit" id="Submit" name= "Submit" value="Upload"></form>');
```

But it doesn't work -Error: ocl is not defined. What can be the reason? If I understand correct in each webpage is an object that contains all javascript functions - so why not possible add or remove function to/from ?

Comment: why do you need this kind of hackery? you are using jQuery and onclick in html?

Comment: That's a horrible idea.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: The web application that I am developing is complicate. It like CRM. It contains near 100 pages. So I need to separate to independent pages - to work in paralell. It seems convenient if each module has own javascript and html

Comment: You can set the event handler after you append the markup using jquery click or bind method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to load js file dynamically, you can try as the following:

Here is the HTML page code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function dynamicLoad() {
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.type="text/javascript";
            s.language="javascript";
            // Here goes your 
            s.src ="dynamic.js";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
            s.onreadystatechange = function() {
                //window.alert(s.readyState);
            }
            s.onload= function() {
                if (s.readyState == "complete") {
 // You must create your DOM element after the js file has been loaded
                    var btn = document.createElement("input");
                    btn.type="button";
                    btn.value="Click Me";
                    btn.onclick = test;
                    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(btn);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="dynamicLoad()">
        <!-- a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="test()">Click Me</a -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the js file:

```
function test() {
    window.alert("HELLO");
}
```

I tested the code under IE 9. Just FYI

Answer (score 2):

The `src` property of the `<script>` tag specifies the URL of an external Javascript file, not the text of the script.

If you want to execute code in an arbitrary string, you can call the `eval` function.
However, **don't**.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you declare a function called **oncl** and you try to call **ocl** (with a **missing n**).

Regards,

Max

Comment: Have a look at SLaks answer (and take into account the comments of the other contributors, maybe you could find another way to do what you are trying to)

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the above answer you have not defined any "ocl" function there is "oncl".