# Appending input tags on click jquery and sending those values to action page

Tags: jquery, html, forms, append, action

I was trying to append input tags on clicking a button and was successful. I refered to many links

[append new rows and input tags using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543135/append-new-rows-and-input-tags-using-jquery)

[JQuery Append javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441049/jquery-append-javascript)

[Jquery appended input button doesn't function with .on(click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636834/jquery-appended-input-button-doesnt-function-with-onclick)

But now the problem is i'm using these input tags in a form and was trying to send those input tag values to next page using form action. But i'm unable send the appended input element values.

**

> jquery

```
$("#addshowtime").click(function(){

    $("<input type='time' value='' />")
     .attr("id", "showtime5")
     .attr("name", "show_timing5")
     .prependTo("#showtime");
    });
```

**

**html**

```
 <label><strong>Show Timing1</strong></label><input id="showtime1" type="time" name="show_timing1"  required/>
    <label><strong>Show Timing2</strong></label><input id="showtime2" type="time" name="show_timing2"  required/>
    <label><strong>Show Timing3</strong></label><input id="showtime3" type="time" name="show_timing3"  required/>
    <label><strong>Show Timing4</strong></label><input id="showtime4" type="time" name="show_timing4"  required/>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<cfinput type="button" id="addshowtime" class="btn" onClick="addInput()" name="add" value="+" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<cfinput type="button" class="btn1" onClick="subInput()" name="sub" value="RESET" />
    <p id="showtime">
    </p>
```

Comment: Show your code to us and explain what exactly is the problem

Comment: Post the code that you had tried.

Comment: so whenever i click on addshowtime button a new input type=time will be appended.On submit the added input's value must be send to the next page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from your code that you must be appending input tag with same id. It will cause an issue if you are capturing the values by detecting input tags by ID.

Comment: k so can i use class instead

Comment: Hey thanks mate it served the purpose. I tried that using class instead and it worked.